# Preg Match word and period before and after

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a preg match working to find all instances of the word title or loan, but could anyone help me modify this to get all instances of the word, plus all words before and after, with a . being the delimiter to stop.

```
preg_match_all('#\b(title|loan)\b#',$html, $matches);
```

Either that, or say 10 words before and 10 words after the word im looking for.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match_all('#(?<pre>\w+) (title|loan) (?<post>\w+)#',$html, $matches);
```

will capture words before and after `title|loan` if they are separated by spaces. Easy enough to tweak if you need more flexible boundaries between your words.

You can then access the matches by:

```
foreach ($matches as $match)
{
  echo $match['pre'];
  echo $match['post'];
}
```

To match everything between periods (sentences) that contain `title|loan`, you can do this:

```
preg_match_all('#[^.]*(title|loan)[^.]*#', $html, $matches);
```

This will match all characters that are not periods before and after `title|loan`.

Comment: That does indeed work, how would you mod this to go 2 letters out, 3 letters out, ect....

Comment: 2 letters out from what? From title|loan?

Comment: Maybe you can help, what im looking for is the right code to find a word, then grab the entire sentence.. So it finds the word, then grabs all words to the left and right, stopping at the period.

Comment: Say Im looking for the word application on this website http://www.titleloansmodesto.com/    - The right code would return "Once you have submitted the application, a loan agent will call you within the hour with your free quote!"